# Using pre rendered html as variable in html file with vueJS

Tags: html, vue.js

I currently have an issue regarding vueJS.

I have a server side application which renders my html and sends it back in a string.

I want to insert this html into my page to display it.

I have it set up like this currently:

Template:

```
<div class="section" v-model="html">
   {{ html.body }}
</div>
```

This outputs the html as a string opposed to rendering it to the page.

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the official `v-html` directive:

```
<div v-html="rawHtml"></div>
```

See [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) for more information.

Comment: Ah, thanks, one more question tho : how would i get my variable ``` {{ html.body }} ``` inside the `v-html` directive ? i cannot bind it with `v-bind` as the example on their page explains.

Comment: HTML is not allowed between curly brackets. Have you tried using `<div v-html="html.body">`? I guess `html.body` is part of the `data` configuration?